# contentsline in hyperref: setting the target link

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the fourth-argument version of `\contentsline` defined in `hyperref`. Is there any way to compute the right hyperlink for the last argument of `\contentsline` in the `hyperref` package automatically, based on its label?

Right now I am using something like this:

```
\addtocontents{myList}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{Title of the entry}{\pageref*{labelForTheEntry}}{othertocsubsection.4.0.14}}
```

Where "othertocsubsection.4.0.14" was set manually by me, which is kind of brittle.

I tried with things like:

```
\addtocontents{myList}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{Title of the entry}{\pageref*{labelForTheEntry}}{\ref{labelForTheEntry}}}
```

but it does not work.

I am trying to reference here a future page, that will be included later. The first option above works, but the problem is that the target link must be set manually.

I include below a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newcommand{\indexNumberOne}{}
\newlistof{myIndexOne}{myIndOne}{\indexNumberOne}
\setcounter{myIndOnedepth}{4}
\newlistentry{myIndexOnechapter}{myIndOne}{0}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnechapter]{myIndexOnesection}{myIndOne}{1}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnesection]{myIndexOnesubsection}{myIndOne}{2}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnesubsection]{myIndexOnesubsubsection}{myIndOne}{3}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\pdfbookmark[1]{Main TOC (documents appear in sequential order)}{MainTOC}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\pdfbookmark[1]{Additional index (documents DO NOT appear in sequential order)}{AdditionalIndex}
\listofmyIndexOne
\cleardoublepage

\addtocontents{myIndOne}{\centerline{\underline{Additional Index}}} 
\addtocontents{myIndOne}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{Document 2}{\pageref*{docTwo}}{section*.2}}
\cleardoublepage

\addtocontents{myIndOne}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{Document 1}{\pageref*{docOne}}{section*.1}}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\label{docOne}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Document 1}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true]{doc1.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\label{docTwo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Document 2}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true]{doc2.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

What I would like is a general solution to replace things like "section*.2" and "section*.1" in such a way that this is computed automatically from the labels (the current links will end up pointing to the wrong place if the order of documents is moved). Any ideas?

Comment: why aren't your section headings setting this automatically, which is the intended behaviour. It is impossible really to suggest how you should change your code if  you show no code.

Comment: Try with `\csname r@labelForTheEntry\endcsname`. Without more detail, it's difficult to answer your question. Can you provide a complete, minimal example that uses your setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow the community to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have added a minimal example in the question.

Comment: `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\setcounter{page}{1}` is doing the same thing twice, basically.

Answer (score 2):

The hyperanchor of a label can be extracted with `\getrefbykeydefault{labelname}{anchor}{some default value}`, where `anchor` is the key and the label name is `docOne` etc. like in this document.

I have provided a small wrapper macro named `\adddoctotoc` which writes to `myIndOne`, requires a entry title and the labelname, then extracts the anchor automatically.

Please note that `\includepdf` has a `toc` feature as well!

The mentioned `dummydocX.pdf` files are created with `LaTeX` using this dummy code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

Here is the working code, it might require three (!!!) runs of compilations in order to get the correct references and anchors!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newcommand{\indexNumberOne}{}
\newlistof{myIndexOne}{myIndOne}{\indexNumberOne}
\setcounter{myIndOnedepth}{4}
\newlistentry{myIndexOnechapter}{myIndOne}{0}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnechapter]{myIndexOnesection}{myIndOne}{1}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnesection]{myIndexOnesubsection}{myIndOne}{2}
\newlistentry[myIndexOnesubsection]{myIndexOnesubsubsection}{myIndOne}{3}

\newcommand{\adddoctotoc}[3][myIndOne]{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{#2}{\getpagerefnumber{#3}}{\getrefbykeydefault{#3}{anchor}{page.1}}}%
}

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\pdfbookmark[1]{Main TOC (documents appear in sequential order)}{MainTOC}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\pdfbookmark[1]{Additional index (documents DO NOT appear in sequential order)}{AdditionalIndex}
\listofmyIndexOne
\cleardoublepage

\addtocontents{myIndOne}{\centerline{\underline{Additional Index}}} 

\adddoctotoc{Document 2}{docTwo}
\adddoctotoc{Document 1}{docOne}
%%\addtocontents{myIndOne}{\string\contentsline{subsection}{Document 1}{\pageref*{docOne}}{section*.1}}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\label{docOne}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Document 1}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true]{dummydoc1.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\phantomsection
\label{docTwo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Document 2}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper=true]{dummydoc2.pdf}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

[image]